# Constructor Doesn't Initialize Online Javascript

Tags: javascript

I just need to reposition elements for app. The starts up locally but not deployed online. I am using "use strict" also.

```
var winHeight=$(window).height();
var winWidth=$(window).width();


var Layout = function(){
  this.half=480;
  this.targetX=960;
  this.targetY=527;
  this.resultX=0;
  this.resultY=0;
  this.compute= function(xx,yy){
   var reX = xx-this.targetX;
   var reY = yy-this.targetY;
   var teX = reX+this.targetX;
   var teY = reY+this.targetY;
   this.resultX=teX/this.targetX;
   this.resultY=teY/this.targetY
  };
};

var layout = new Layout();
layout.compute(winWidth,winHeight);
```

Comment: thats a function *expression*.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to say: `function ClassName()`

```
function Layout() { 
    ... 
};
```

Comment: You don't need the trailing `;`